# When does 木 as a character component get detached legs?

Tags: characters, calligraphy, strokes

Is there any discernible rule concerning whether 木 as a component of a character has attached legs (as in 李) or has detached legs (as in 新)? Worse, this seems to [vary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%96%B0#Alternative_forms) from country to country.

Comment: Anecdotal: **on the bottom**. I never see it detached on the left, top, or right. No evidence for this assertion, hope a calligrapher can clarify. By the way, in Traditional Print forms, 木 never gets detached - if you see something that's detached, it is not 木 (or what Traditionally is considered 木; e.g. 余 should be detached). The rise of detached 木 legs is from brush calligraphy.

Comment: There’s many common hanzi with 木 on the bottom e.g. 桌集, looking up the radical in Pleco gives only very rare characters e.g. 鎥 without the detached radical at the bottom.

Comment: So I'd venture to formulate this rule: If at all, the 木 with detached legs appears in a bottom position. A hanzi thus formed may, however, appear anywhere as a component of a complex hanzi.

But is there any pattern concerning the use of attached/detached legs in the bottom position?

Comment: Legs? Trees have legs? I read the old meaning of 朩 is 'bush'. Not too much difference between tree and bush. Maybe the 2 were mixed in history. Certainly, looking at old forms of 木 and 朩, they look the same.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify which stander you are talking about. Appearance of characters may different in mainland / hongkong / taiwan. The same characters may looks different in that case.

Answer (score 5):

To start off,「木」is **not supposed to** have detached legs and end up looking like「朩」. In one of the most stringent glyph standards, [*Kangxi Dictionary style Ming (Serif)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_Chinese_character#Orthodox_and_vulgar_variants), if the [*Shuowen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi) [small seal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script) shape contains「木」, then it does not have detached legs.

[image]

This is for glyph shape fidelity reasons, and conversely, if it has detached legs, you can be certain that, at the very least, the *Kangxi Dictionary* didn't think that it came from the component「木」.

[image]

Of course, this sometimes doesn't turn out correctly, as with ancient characters which were no longer used, such as「亲」and characters which use it as a component.

[image]

> For reference,「亲」(*hazel tree*) is a variation of「」, and is constructed from semantic「木」and phonetic「辛」. This word is now written as「榛」.
>
> <kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
> [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
> [image]
> 中伯壺
> [集成9668](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=9668&jgwfl=)</kbd>
> <kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
> [image]
> [木部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77390&page=59)
> 說文解字</kbd><kbd>臺標
> [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
> [image]</kbd>
>
> 　<kbd>臺標
> [隸定](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E9%9A%B6%E5%AE%9A)
> [image]</kbd>

Detached legs on「木」are strictly an invention from calligraphy, and overwhelmingly occur on the bottom of characters:

[image]

Thus, all character shapes directly affected by calligraphy, including those set by government standards, will have a chance of containing「木」appearing with detached legs. This is purely a shape phenomenon - it has nothing to do with the language.

---

Characters which are affected by calligraphy are:

(1) **The Taiwanese MoE standard**, which actively prescribes writing「木」on the bottom as「朩」, and this effect has bled into their print fonts.

[image]

(2) **PRC's regularised cursive shapes**

[image]

*But I guess it is arguable whether regularised cursive is appropriate for any kind of character shape analysis.*

Comment: I noticed some characters like 宋 or 采, while having 木 on the bottom, will have the two strokes attached, unlike the Taiwanese shape for 桌. I read (I can't find the source on this anymore) that there can only be one instance of the following three strokes in a character: 鉤, 捺, 長橫. This supposedly explains why 木 is written like that sometimes when on the bottom, and also some other differences like why 七 is written without the hook in the Taiwanese shape. However, it seems somewhat inconsistent, like how 榮 has them detached, but none of those three strokes are present. Any ideas on why this is?

Comment: Update: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Form_of_National_Characters
`This standard tends to follow a rule of writing regular script where there should be no more than one of ㇏ (called 捺), long horizontal stroke, or hook to the right (e.g. ㇂ ㇃) in a character.`

Comment: @wang_xiao_ming I'm still hoping that a calligrapher can clarify. Calligraphy (regular script or otherwise) is not my area of reading.